# peewee.OperationalError: database is locked on a single Thread using a locker

Tags: python, database, peewee

I get the issue like 1/10000 times.

I have this single code to update the value.

I have other places used the database but it seems only this code is crashing with database
lock, or it just that this once called most often.

```
class InstaPyLimits(object):
    @staticmethod
    def update_daily_activity(time):
        with ActivityTracker_locker:
            # ActivityTracker.update(activity_time_curr= ActivityTracker.activity_time_curr + int(time)).where(ActivityTracker.date == _datetime.date.today()).execute()
            ActivityTracker.update(
                {ActivityTracker.activity_time_curr: ActivityTracker.activity_time_curr + int(time)}).where(
                ActivityTracker.date == _datetime.date.today()).execute()

models.py:
db = SqliteDatabase(Settings.stats_conf_database_location)
ActivityTracker_locker = threading.Lock()


class ActivityTracker(Model):
    date = DateField(unique=True)
    activity_time_curr = IntegerField(default=0)  # active seconds today
    activity_time_max = IntegerField()   # max active seconds today

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

I spent half a day moving and testing, I think it might be in the way I call the update.

Comment: Looks like a race condition: something else is trying to write to the DB at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition somewhere. It doesn't matter that you have a lock around it -- you need to ensure that your *transaction boundaries* are what is contained within the lock.

```
@staticmethod
def update_daily_activity(time):
    with ActivityTracker_locker:
        with db.atomic() as txn:
            ActivityTracker.update(...).execute()
```

Similarly, depending on whether you're using WAL-mode or not, you'll need to ensure your other threads do not have open write transactions (or possibly read transactions if not using WAL-mode).

To use WAL-mode:

```
db = SqliteDatabase(
    Settings.stats_conf_database_location,
    pragmas={'journal_mode': 'wal'})
```

You need to use WAL-mode from the beginning, so it may be necessary to dump and reload your data.

Comment: Why Atomic and WAL mode is needed here ?

Comment: as I get it there are 2 threads opened by peewee, one for write and one for read, normally the read will lock the database first, later the write will, but for some race condition when journal is DELETED not WAL the write lock before the read does creating a database is locked.

Comment: Your understanding is completely wrong as far as I can tell

Comment: Using the WAL mode fixed the issue.
BUT, they issues I think is not im my program, but on WINDOWS, I have 5 differnt windows PC each run 150 processes with sqlite, some PC dont get the database is locked at all, if a sudden crash of the pc happen, the issue shows up again 10 times / day ... not sure what is wrong, I just changeed the pragma to WAL hope it will not make another issues.